# Cordova delete files after sqlite delete it

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this app where I take picture or select it from gallery then move it into file-system , save the imgpath for the image into sqlite db and display it, everything works great so far , now when I delete the imgpath from the sqlite db , I want to delete it from file-system at the same time .

```
$scope.deleteImg = function(imgPath) {


    if (!imgPath) {
        console.error("No fileName specified. File could not be deleted.");
        return false;
    } else {


        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, imgPath.id).then(function() {
            $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, imgPath.id).then(function(result) {
                console.log("image '" + imgPath + "' deleted", JSON.stringify(result));
            }, function(err) {
                console.error("Failed to delete file '" + imgPath.id + "'", JSON.stringify(err));

            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("image '" + imgPath.id + "' does not exist", JSON.stringify(err));
        });

    }

    $scope.add = function(path) { 
             
            console.log("I AM ADDING TO DB WITH PATH: " + path);   

              
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "INSERT INTO imageTable (image) VALUES(?)", [path]).then(
                function(res) {
                    console.log("I AM DONE ADDING TO DB");   
                }
            );                


                  
        },
        function(e) {        
            alert(e);      
        };



        

      
    $scope.ShowAllData = function() {
        console.log("I AM READING FROM DB");   
        $scope.images = [];             
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT * FROM imageTable ORDER BY id DESC"  ).then(        function(res) {

            console.log("I FINISHED READING  FROM DB");   

                      
            if (res.rows.length > 0) {            
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {              
                    $scope.images.push({
                        id: res.rows.item(i).id,
                        image: res.rows.item(i).image

                                      
                    });

                }          
            } 
            return $scope.images;

                    
        },         function(error) {          
            alert(error);        
        }      );

            
    }  

    $scope.getImgIDbyName = function(name) {

        console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - get image with name:  ' + name);
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM imageTable WHERE image = '" + name + "';";
        console.log(sql);
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,
            sql
        ).then(
            function(res) {
                if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                    if (res.rows.length > 1) {
                        console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - OOPS more than 1 image returned!!!!  ' + name);
                    } else {
                        $scope.delete(res.rows.item(0).id);
                        $scope.deleteImg(imagePath.id);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - no image found with name:  ' + name);
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("error occured: " + error.message);
            }
        );



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the plugin - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

and then execute the following code

```
var path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/res/image'; // get the absolute path
var filename = "image.png";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.remove(function(){
                  // The file has been removed succesfully
              },function(error){
                  // Error deleting the file
              },function(){
                 // The file doesn't exist
              });
    });
});
```

Here is the complete documentation : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files

Comment: Thanks for your help , I have already install the plugin and I use it to save the image into filesystem , you can check my full code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109744/how-to-save-image-path-in-sqlite-cordova

Comment: how can  I delete the imgpath from filesystem after it deleted from the db , that's where I struggle in , I need to pass same id to deleteImg for filesystem

Comment: Let me take a look at your code here. So, you have problem of getting that id/filename from sqlite?

Comment: Already see your code. So, you save image to data directory. cordova.file.dataDirectory, try retrieve all the file in data directory what you will get.

Comment: You're in wrong directory. $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, imgPath.id). Please change that to cordova.file.dataDirectory

Comment: Thank you , I will try and let you know .

Comment: I have called the function like that after the delete from db , $scope.deleteImg(res.rows.item(0).imagePath); is that correct !

Comment: The possible way is you should delete from file system first before delete path in db.

Comment: cordova need to know the imagepath from db before it need to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I marked your answer , I will try it and hopefully it will work :)

Comment: When you store imagePath in the db, that is not the true absolute path for url. You should use cordova.file.dataDirectory to get absolute url and combine with new image name that you had save to the sqlite db. In, this case, imagePath is not needed, only imageName/filename. Thanks

Comment: imgPath is the true path , I did it this way       var imgPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + newFileName;

Comment: Hello , I'm facing problem of deleting the camera cache picture , for example after taking the picture with the camera and crop it , it generate the cropped one and original one , i move the cropped image path to db but i can't find a way to delete the original one .
I figure out there $cordova.cleanup() for IOS , is there any for android

Comment: By default, this library will create the image in the cache when you take photo. You can use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera. It have cleanup method . You can use it to delte temp photo after taking picture for i:e navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess, onFail);

Comment: Yes , but that cleanup method , only for IOS not android

Comment: Don't need it in android since it does not store cache i think. You should try it first. iOS stores the images taken with the camera into the /tmp folder, if you close the app, /tmp folder is deleted aswell, but you have to close it manually, if you just quit the app enters background and /tmp isn't deleted.

Comment: unfortunately  it does , check my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272113/cordova-camera-clean-up-cache-android

Comment: What plugin 're u using?

Comment: $cordovaCamera  plugin